# Should string object property representing a number be a string or number

Tags: swagger, swagger-editor

As stated in the title, my team always sends a response of which properties which represent float/int/bigInteger as strings, should the swagger type of those properties be number or a string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data type in your OpenAPI definition must indicate the actual data type used in the payload.

If the response is

```json
{
  "id": "12345"
}
```

then `id` is a `type: string` property.

You can use `format` and `pattern` (regex pattern) to clarify the value format. For example, if `id` strings contains non-negative integer numbers, you can define `id` as:

```yaml
type: string
pattern: "^\\d+$"
```